# Why the SaveChanges() can't work when I try to finish the SportStore Demo in the book of Pro ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

```
public void SaveProduct(Product product)
{
    if (product.ProductID == 0)
         {
            context.Products.Add(product);
         }   
     //Oops~~~
     context.SaveChanges();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Product product)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        repository.SaveProduct(product);
        //I can see this msg int the view page. but database never changed.!!
        TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", product.Name);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        // there is something wrong with the data values
        return View(product);
    }
}
```

I got stuck with this problem and don't know how to make the data be stored into the database. The problem occurs when I try to save changes to an existing product.
Can anyone tell me  why the saveChanges() method called and datas never saved to the db? THX

Comment: Are you sure you went into the .Add method?  Were any exceptions thrown?

Comment: No, no exceptions . I just modify the data and called context.SaveChanges(). .Add method can only be called when I add a new product. But I just wanna update. man`~~

Comment: When I try to debug , I found the product object's data is changed to the new one, but wirely it can;t be saved to the database.

Comment: to narrow down your scope of investigation, open Sql Profiler while debugging and see if the right insert command is sent to the database when context.SaveChanges(); is called. A note that if your product does not have primary key in db side, it cannot be persisted into the database by calling context.SaveChanges();

Comment: I can't see any insert statement in the Sql Profiler . There are some select Statement and many thing else but insert related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity `product` constructed by model binding is NOT automatically attached to the context. The context therefore is not aware of any change to save. You have to attach the product first and set it's state to modified.

```
context.Products.Attach(product);
// When setting the entry state to Modified
// all the properties of the entity are marked as modified.
context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Now you can call `context.SaveChanges();`.

Comment: It is the book <Pro ASP.Net MVC 3> 's bug, I can't find that two statement in this book. thx again.